# How to deploy Java project to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I have downloaded a sample extjs+mysql+spring web project ([link](https://github.com/loiane/ext4-crud-mvc)) with a java backend that I'd like to set up locally on my machine. I have installed Tomcat server, and MySQL DB but it's my first time ever with a java-based web application and I have troubles setting it up. Does it require any modifications ? I thought that .jsp files should be included there, but I can only see .java sources. Do I need to build it before it's ready for deployment ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Eclipse project so you'd need to run it from within Eclipse.

- [Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) Eclipse
- Open the project in it
- Define a Tomcat container in your Servers tab
- Drag and drop the project onto the newly defined Tomcat
- Run it

Comment: well, guess it's not as easy as 1,2,3 as I'm getting some weird type errors but at least I know the correct path now :)

Answer (score 1):

if your are using eclipse IDE for development, create a project in eclipse,
run as "run on server" , and set the running server (eg TOMCAT 7).
and thats it,,
make sure, you correctly setup spring project in IDE with all needed jar files .